# GET request on HTTP after 3-way handshake

Tags: html, python-2.7, http, tcp, scapy

I want to make a program that interacts with a server such as google and makes a 3-way handshake with him. After that i want to send a GET request to find the html part of the page.
When do i need to insert the GET request?
Thank you.

That's the 3-way handshake i made:

```
sport = random.randint(1024,65535)

# SYN     
ip=IP(src='192.168.23.131',dst='81.17.241.142')
SYN=TCP(sport=sport,dport=443,flags='S',seq=1000)
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)

# ACK          
ACK=TCP(sport=sport, dport=443, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack + 1, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ip/ACK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Threeway handshake establishes a connection between the client and a server. After the connection is established under the HTTP protocol, the client is to submit a request to the resources he wants to access. Keep in mind that on every packet you send you will get an ACK packet, and for every packet you receive you should send an ACK packet.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `ACK` sequence number should be `SYNACK.ack`, not `SYNACK.ack + 1`. You can send your request directly after the handshake (assuming you want to send an HTTP/1.1 request):

```
sport = random.randint(1024,65535)
dport = 443
ip_src = '192.168.23.131'
ip_dst = '81.17.241.142'

# SYN     
ip=IP(src=ip_src, dst=ip_dst)
SYN=TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='S', seq=1000)
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)

# ACK          
ACK=TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ip/ACK)

# GET request
req =  "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
req += "Host: " + ip_dst + "\r\n"
# Other headers ...
req += "\r\n"

DATA = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)/req
ANS = sr1(DATA) # this is probably going to be only an ACK segment, next one should be your HTTP response
```